# Reload Fragment as if screen would rotate

Tags: android, fragment, reload

I built a quiz and in my fragment the question + answers are shown.
Every time the user chooses an answer, a dialog is shown and the user can decide whether or not to keep on playing. At the moment i react to it as following:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityQuiz.class));
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
```

but this seems slow. I'd rather reload the fragment, like when the screen rotates.
How can I do this?

This is the rest of the code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv_question;
    Button btn_answer_1;
    Button btn_answer_2;
    Button btn_answer_3;
    JSONArray jArray = null;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_quiz, container, false);

        ...
        btn_answer_1.setOnClickListener(btn_answer_listener);
        btn_answer_2.setOnClickListener(btn_answer_listener);
        btn_answer_3.setOnClickListener(btn_answer_listener);

        ...

        return rootView;
    }

 public OnClickListener btn_answer_listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int id = v.getId();

            if (id == R.id.btn_answer_1 && Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWER() == 1) {
                // correct
                answerCorrect();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.btn_answer_2 && Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWER() == 2) {
                // correct
                answerCorrect();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.btn_answer_3 && Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWER() == 3) {
                // correct
                answerCorrect();
            }
            else {
                answerWrong();
            }

        }

    };

    private void answerCorrect() {

        //Globals.incrementAnswersTotal(); // got to become sharedPreference
        Globals.INCREMENT_ANSWERS_ROUND();
        //Globals.incrementCorrectAnswersTotal(); // sharedPreference
        Globals.INCREMENT_CORRECT_ANSWERS_ROUND();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_ic_dialog_correct));
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_correct_answer_heading));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_correct_answer_text) + "\n\n" + Globals.getREMARK());
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ad_keep_on, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityQuiz.class));
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }

        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.ad_to_menu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityAppLaunch.class));
            }

        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    private void answerWrong() {

        //Globals.incrementAnswersTotal(); // got to become sharedPreference
        Globals.INCREMENT_ANSWERS_ROUND(); 

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_ic_dialog_wrong));
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_wrong_answer_heading));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_wrong_answer_text) + "\"" + Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWER_TEXT() + "\"" + "\n\n" + Globals.getREMARK());
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ad_keep_on, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityQuiz.class));
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }

        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.ad_to_menu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityAppLaunch.class));
            }

        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you just add a method to the fragment telling it to load new data? Without seeing more of your code of how loading questions/answers is done, I can't tell you much more than that.

Comment: I edited it. Basically I have a few buttons that are connected with an OnClickListener. This listener calls a function and in this function the dialog is displayed. From there I'd like to reload the fragment, or better reload `onCreateView` of my Fragment

Comment: How are you loading questions into the fragment?

Comment: Im retrieving a JSONArray from an URL.

Comment: Is that done in `onCreateView(...)` of your fragment?

Comment: yes, I'm doing everything in onCreateView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing everything in `onCreateView(...)` is probably not ideal. Your best option is to move everything related to loading a question to its own method. In `onCreateView(...)`, inflate your views and store local references to them. Then, override one of the fragment lifecycle methods that are garanteed to be called after that, such as `onActivityCreated()` and call the loading method from there; this would get the question and populate the views with the right data. Then, whenever you want a new question, simply call that loading method to repopulate the views with the new questions and answers. I can provide pseudocode if needed.

Edit: here is some pseudocode illustrating what I mean. This is by no means valid code but it is the basis of what you should be doing.

```
class Fragment {
    private TextView question
    private TextView answer

    onCreateView {
        View v = inflate view
        question = view.findView(question)
        answer = view.findView(answer)
    }

    onActivityCreated {
        loadQuestionAndAnswer()
    }

    loadQuestionAndAnswer {
        JSON json = Interwebs.getJSON()
        question.setText(json.getQuestion())
        answer.setText(json.getAnswer())
    }

    Dialog.onClick {
        loadQuestionAndAnswer()
    }
}
```

Comment: I only have to questions about this. Is this faster than loading the whole activity with an intent as I did it now and how to call the onActivityCreated method from my dialog?

Comment: It will absolutely be faster! Activity/Fragment creation is a very expensive operation. You should generally prefer methods that avoid having to create new Activities or Fragments. You don't need to call `onActivityCreated`, that is called automatically by the android framework (more about the fragment lifecycle can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). The purpose of calling it there and not in `onViewCreated()` is that then you are guaranteed to have an instance of all the views you want to populate.

Comment: In your `DialogFragment`, you shouldn't be invoking fragment lifecycle commands. You should simply call YOUR method that reload the data.

Comment: can you help me out with a litte piece of code? I'm not quite getting it yet.

Comment: Absolutely. One minute.